# Does it matter Sitecore CM connect to Solr Cloud leader vs follower?

Tags: solr, content-search, indexing

We currently have our Solr Cloud with zookeeper and for front with load balance (Solr Prd1 and Prd2). CM is connecting to Solr Prd1 (leader) and CDs are connecting to Solr load balance.

Questions:

- Does it matter for CM to connect to Solr leader or follower?
- Whichever Solr server that CM is connected to, the Solr server CPU is gearing up high almost 80% all the time. What could be the issue? Is this issue related to index strategy or server resource needs to be scale?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that any server in an  Zookeeper Ensemble (3 or more Zookeeper instances used to form a SolrCloud) can be elected a leader or a follower at any time if the current leader disconnects from the Ensemble.

As far as I’m aware all nodes are kept up to date and updates to the leader are asynchronously made to the followers. Therefore this shouldn’t pose too much of an issue.

With regard to the performance issue, there are a number of things that can affect this. Solr needs a fair bit of RAM allocated to it so check this but also look at your index update strategy, how often rebuilds are being triggered (check the Sitecore logs) and also how many items you have in you index. You could look to shard your index if it’s very large or to have index updates only run on the leader but queries run on the followers. It depends on a number of things though.

This is a really great blog series on setting up solr cloud and part 4 includes tuning things like the JVM memory: http://www.chrissulham.com/sitecore-on-solr-cloud-part-4/

Comment: Thanks Adam. Great information in your provided link as well.

Comment: No worries. glad it was useful.